# kivy on android, background service notification never disppears

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

As you know, for creating a background service for your kivy app, by adding a folder named 'service' to the root projects directory and writing your service inside that folder in a file named `main.py` and building the kivy app for android using `buildozer`, you can have a service running in the background on your application start-up. In you `build()` method you could do the following to start it.

```
    def build(self):
        if platform == 'android':
            import android
            service = android.AndroidService('Notification Name', 'Notification Message')
            service.start('Service args')
```

But this creates a notification that shows up on app-start up and never disappears. A notification that opens the kivy app on selection and doesn't go away if you select it. Does anybody know how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually if you use the second method [here](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/services/) (of course with `--bootstrap sdl2`), such notification won't appear anoymore. Also something that was unclear for me a while was the path in `--service` [which is meant as a path from your current directory to the python file when packaging](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/issues/1020).